# Maven plugin jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin not generating pojos for all the definitions

Tags: java, json, maven, jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

We are using jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin to generate the java pojos from a json schema file. The plugin is generating the pojos for the definitions that are referred from the schema but not for all the definitions.

Is there any option to make the plugin generate the pojos for all the definitions in the schmea?

Below are the pom plugin configurations and schema definitions used, here the plugin is

- generating POJOs only for the **product** definition
- not generating POJOs for the **product subclass** definitions ("**proprietaryProduct**" & "**thirdPartyProduct**")

this is the problem, we need to have the pojos generated for these subclass definitions as well

**Maven Plugin configuration:**

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-models</id>
                <configuration>
                    <targetPackage>com.xyz.abc</targetPackage>
                    <useCommonsLang3>true</useCommonsLang3>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

**Json Schema:**

```
{
  "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
  "definitions":{
    "product":{
      "type":"object",
      "properties":{
        "type":{
          "enum":[
            "THIRD_PARTY",
            "PROPRIETARY"
          ],
          "type":"string"
        },
        "price":{
          "type":"string"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "proprietaryProduct": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "batchName": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "extends": "#/definitions/product"
    },
    "thirdPartyProduct": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "thirdPartyName": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "extends": "#/definitions/product"
    }
  },
  "type":"object",
  "properties":{
    "product":{
      "type":"object",
      "$ref":"#/definitions/product"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties":false
}
```

Comment: What log messages do you get. Have you run maven with the -X verbose mode to see what the plugin is doing?

Comment: Maven log is not giving much of a clue - it is detecting only Product Class Definition, but not the subclass definitions. But when I add reference in the schema using any of the subclass definitions (like "$ref":"#/definitions/proprietaryProduct") - the corresponding subclass POJO is being created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to generate unreferenced parts of the definitions by using a custom schema rule factory, in a new maven project :

```java
package my.package;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.sun.codemodel.JClassContainer;
import com.sun.codemodel.JType;
import org.jsonschema2pojo.Schema;
import org.jsonschema2pojo.rules.Rule;
import org.jsonschema2pojo.rules.RuleFactory;
import org.jsonschema2pojo.rules.SchemaRule;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class JsonSchemaRuleFactory extends RuleFactory {

    @Override
    public Rule<JClassContainer, JType> getSchemaRule() {
        return new MySchemaRule(this);
    }

    private class MySchemaRule extends SchemaRule {

        public MySchemaRule(JsonSchemaRuleFactory jsonSchemaRuleFactory) {
            super(jsonSchemaRuleFactory);
        }

        @Override
        public JType apply(String nodeName, JsonNode schemaNode, JsonNode parent, JClassContainer generatableType, Schema schema) {
            final JType apply = super.apply(nodeName, schemaNode, parent, generatableType, schema);

            final JsonNode definitions = schemaNode.get("definitions");
            if (definitions != null && definitions.isObject()) {
                ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) definitions;
                final Iterator<String> nodeIterator = objectNode.fieldNames();
                while (nodeIterator.hasNext()) {
                    final String name = nodeIterator.next();
                    try {
                        final ObjectNode node = (ObjectNode) objectNode.get(name);
                        final Schema currentSchema = getSchemaStore().create(schema, "#/definitions/" + name, getGenerationConfig().getRefFragmentPathDelimiters());
                        getSchemaRule().apply(name, node, schemaNode, generatableType.getPackage(), currentSchema);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            return apply;
        }
    }
}
```

new dedicated maven project :

```xml
<project>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonschema-with-all-definitions</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    // ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then I modified the configuration of the jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin as seen below:

```xml
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>generateClassesFromSchema</id>
                                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>generate</goal>
                                </goals>

                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            // ...                            
<customRuleFactory>my.package.JsonSchemaRuleFactory</customRuleFactory>
                        </configuration>

                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>my.group</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jsonschema-with-all-definitions</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0.0</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
```

As the jsonschema aren't mine and I can't edit/correct them, I used MixIns which I registered in my ObjectMapper to add some annotations that are missing from generated classes, such as @JsonTypeInfo or else.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer (as a workaround solution) as it might be helpful for someone who is facing the same challenge.

After researching and reading through the jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin:generate documentation, I've understood that it is not possible to make this plugin generate POJOs for the unreferenced definitions in the schema.

As a work around, we could define them as separate json-schema definition and make the plugin generate the pojos for it.

So, I have to create separate schema definition for each subclass (in this case - #/definitions/proprietaryProduct need to defined as a separate schema definition)

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer (as a workaround solution) as it might be helpful for someone who is facing the same challenge.

After researching and reading through the jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin:generate documentation, I've understood that it is not possible to make this plugin generate POJOs for the unreferenced definitions in the schema.

So I believe the json schema definition showen in the example is wrong, so the plugin can't generate the POJOs.

The json schema should follow the rules defined at http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema

Something like this should work better

```
{
"$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
"description":"Products definition",
"type":"object,"
"properties":{
"product":{
  "type":"object",
  "properties":{
    "type":{
      "enum":[
        "THIRD_PARTY",
        "PROPRIETARY"
      ],
      "type":"string"
    },
    "price":{
      "type":"string"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
},
```

... and so on
}

I did try, it works